# How to make ACE/TAO service setup more user-friendly?

Tags: corba, tao

The standard way of setting up a network of applications communicating over the ACE/TAO CORBA framework has always been

1. run the naming service
2. run the event channel
3. run your applications

I'd like to alleviate my end-users from having to spawn multiple background services by hand and am looking for a clean solution. I'd also like to have my networks as plug 'n play as possible. That means we're synchronizing various hardware components with the help of a central controller instance. Each of these pairings  makes up an (isolated) network, so we can have multiples of these in one environment and don't want any interference between them.

My idea was to just spawn a naming service and and event service on the controller's initialization but I haven't found a nice way yet to spawn both processes (tao_cosnaming, tao_rtevent) as child processes, so that they are really tied to the controller instance and don't keep running if the controller crashes i.e. Is there already a mechanism inside TAO that allows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Implementation Repository could do this for you. Another option is to just link the Naming Service and Event Channel into your controller, just one process that also delivers these services.

Comment: I've read a bit into the function of the implementation repository now but it seems to only delay the problem since I now have to start the repository processes before using them.
Can you elaborate a bit more on how to link these services into my controller executable? You mean statically or by using the dlls?

Comment: You can just use the DLLs and create the instances of the services yourself, just copy the code of the main of the mentioned services.